# Sorting tables Javascript

Tags: html, html-table, dom-events, columnsorting

I'm sorting a table when a user clicks on the table head, and I'm using vanilla Javascript to do this. I'm trying to capture the column number by clicking the `<th>` table head and pass it to the `sortTable(n)` function. Also, I'm trying to start the `sortTable(n)` function after column data is captured. I'm not sure where my error is at?

```js
document.getElementById('myTable2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myFunction(event)
}, true);

function myFunction() {
  var col = window.event.target.cellIndex;
  var n = col;
  sortTable(n);
  return n;

}

function sortTable(n) {
  var n = myFunction();
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
  switching = true;
  
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
   switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir === "asc") {
        if (x.textContenttextContent.toLowerCase() > y.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir === "desc") {
        if (x.textContent.toLowerCase() < y.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
       if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew. There were a fair amount of coding problems in the way you called the eventHandler "myFunction()". There were also some very dangerous habits you were falling into regarding variable scope. I rewrote those. On the upside, your application logic was sound. Good job! [I wrote a pen that works to show it to you in action if the snippet doesn't](https://codepen.io/vipatron/pen/vVOMbM). But, follow my advice about changing variable names, especially if this is for an assignment.

```js
document.getElementById('myTable2').addEventListener('click', myFunction, true);

function myFunction(event) {
  // window.alert("In myFunction");
  // console.log(event);
  
  var col = event.target.cellIndex;
  //Following line was redundant;
  //var n = col;
  sortTable(col);
  return col;

}


//PIECE OF ADVICE: If you renamed the variable "n" to "selectedCol", it would be more readable. Or at least "col"
function sortTable(n) {
  // WHY are you redeclaring the argument?
  // And why are you assigning myFunction, which called this function, as the object which you are assigning to n?
//   var n = myFunction();

  // OLD VERSION: All declared and set to 0, then later reassigned: Confusing and can get you into problems with variable scope, and unused declarations. 
  // var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  var switchcount = 0;
  
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
  var switching = true;
  var dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {
   switching = false;
   var rows = table.rows;
    var shouldSwitch;

    /* Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers): */
    for (var i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      // Start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next: */
      var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      var y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /* Check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc: */
      if (dir === "asc") {
        if (x.textContent.toLowerCase() > y.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir === "desc") {
        if (x.textContent.toLowerCase() < y.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
          // If so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      // Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount++;
    } else {
       if (switchcount === 0 && dir === "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table id = "myTable2" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did not know I redeclared the argument.  is there a way to have just the header <th> as the clickable area versus the whole column? I assume I need to change "event.target.cellIndex"

Comment: Just so we're clear, when you hang an eventListener on an element, you have 2 choices: You can define an anonymous function right there, as you sorta tried to do, or you can name it, as I did in my solution. As to your second question, I would check to see whether `event.target.nodeNAME==="TH"`, and only call sortTable() if that were true.    EDIT: Also, if you accepted my answer, would you mind upvoting it?